# One php file to another?

Tags: php, variables, include

I need a function to pull the following php code from one php "variables page" (or other simple file) to the php file I want to use it on.

I tried echo include but couldn't get it to work.

```
<?php
    $option1 = 1;
    $option2 = 2;
    $option3 = 3;
    $option4 = 4;
    $option5 = 5;
?>
```

Comment: You have to use `echo $option1;` if you want to show the variables. If you use `include`, only the file is included. No magic will occur.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`require`](http://php.net/require) or [`include`](http://php.net/include). Or, if you want to make sure the variables file doesn't get included more than once, you can use [`require_once`](http://php.net/require_once) or [`include_once`](http://php.net/include_once).

```
require "variables_page.php";
```

The difference between `require` and `include` is that `require` makes the script fail if the file cannot be found, while `include` only issues a warning. Usually you should prefer `require`.

Also note that `require` and `include` are language constructs, not functions, so there's no need to surround the parameter by parenthesis.

Comment: @Smamatti, added that as an option. Usually though if you include a file with local variables, it's not obvious if the file is indeed supposed to be loaded only once. It would be obvious, for example, if the file would contain a class definition.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use `require_once("variables_page.php");`

Difference betwen include functions:

> The two functions are identical in every way, except how they handle
>   errors:
>
> - include() generates a warning, but the script will continue execution
> - require() generates a fatal error, and the script will stop

(from http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp)

Use require_once or include_once if you want to make sure that the file is included only one time.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
require_once()
```

or

```
include_once()
```

functions.

argument - is file name. 
If same folder use as

```
require_once( "file.php" )
```